# Initializing empty object in Go

Tags: go

I will use exec.Command with different arguments depending on a variable.  I do `cmd := exec.Command(...` in the if/else brackets , so `cmd` is unusable outside of that scope.  Is it possible to initialize `cmd` above if/else so that it can be used afterward?

Comment: `var cmd *exec.Cmd` (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

Comment: @mkopriva - thanks, put it in an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a typed variable before you have a value for it.

```
 var cmd *exec.Cmd
 // or
 cmd := (*exec.Cmd)(nil)
```

Read more here https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables and here https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations.